# Time series analysis for multiple features

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, prophet

I wanted to get some ideas around how I can implement this project.
I have a dataset having 3 columns, 2 categorical columns A and B and a column Count. This data is generated every 5 mins in a different file with timestamp. I want to predict the next 5-6 iterations based on previous data for each combination of A and B.

My solution was to build a different model for each combination but it would be very hard to maintain.

Is there a better solution for this prediction?

Also since this is generated every 5 mins. I would need to append the data and retrain every 5 mins to predict for the next 25 - 20 mins. Is there any other better approach to this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.